# multi vue app in single domain nginx the second app does not work

Tags: vue.js, nginx, vuetify.js

samuimall.com/pose works perfect but samuimall.com/smartq is giving error

> GET https://samuimall.com/assets/index.7f6e6985.js net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)

I googled it but no idea what this problem came from

```
 location /pose {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/samuimall.com/pose/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        index index.html;
    }

    location /smartq {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/samuimall.com/smartq/dist;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        index index.html;
    }
```